# Wt a.exe file won't run

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, wt

I am trying to start developing in WT, but it's not working out. I am using Windows 8, downloaded Wt 3.3.1, and had downloaded the codeblocks-12.11mingw-setup_user.exe which has the GCC compiler and GDB debugger. But I am not using code blocks, because the compiler didn't like the cmake preproccessor directives in WtConfig.h. So I tried to compile manually (I am a newb at using this type of technique, so I had to look it up).

I have my project as:

```
└───HelloWorldWt
    └───source
        ├───bin
        │   ├───Debug
        │   │   └───CMakeFiles
        │   │       └───CMakeFiles
        │   └───Release
        ├───build
        └───source
        |   └───CMakeFiles
        |       └───wt_project.wt.dir
        |       |___CMakeLists.txt
        |       |
        |       |___main.cpp
        |____CMakeLists.txt
```

The main.cpp has (this is the HelloWorld example from http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/examples/):

/*
 * Copyright (C) 2008 Emweb bvba, Heverlee, Belgium.
 *
 * See the LICENSE file for terms of use.
 */

```
#include <Wt/WApplication>
#include <Wt/WBreak>
#include <Wt/WContainerWidget>
#include <Wt/WLineEdit>
#include <Wt/WPushButton>
#include <Wt/WText>

// c++0x only, for std::bind
// #include <functional>

using namespace Wt;

/*
 * A simple hello world application class which demonstrates how to react
 * to events, read input, and give feed-back.
 */
class HelloApplication : public WApplication
{
public:
  HelloApplication(const WEnvironment& env);

private:
  WLineEdit *nameEdit_;
  WText *greeting_;

  void greet();
};

/*
 * The env argument contains information about the new session, and
 * the initial request. It must be passed to the WApplication
 * constructor so it is typically also an argument for your custom
 * application constructor.
*/
HelloApplication::HelloApplication(const WEnvironment& env)
  : WApplication(env)
{
  setTitle("Hello world");                               // application title

  root()->addWidget(new WText("Your name, please ? "));  // show some text
  nameEdit_ = new WLineEdit(root());                     // allow text input
  nameEdit_->setFocus();                                 // give focus

  WPushButton *button
    = new WPushButton("Greet me.", root());              // create a button
  button->setMargin(5, Left);                            // add 5 pixels margin

  root()->addWidget(new WBreak());                       // insert a line break

  greeting_ = new WText(root());                         // empty text

  /*
   * Connect signals with slots
   *
   * - simple Wt-way
   */
  button->clicked().connect(this, &HelloApplication::greet);

  /*
   * - using an arbitrary function object (binding values with boost::bind())
   */
  nameEdit_->enterPressed().connect
    (boost::bind(&HelloApplication::greet, this));

  /*
   * - using a c++0x lambda:
   */
  // b->clicked().connect(std::bind([=]() {
  //       greeting_->setText("Hello there, " + nameEdit_->text());
  // }));
}

void HelloApplication::greet()
{
  /*
   * Update the text, using text input into the nameEdit_ field.
   */
  greeting_->setText("Hello there, " + nameEdit_->text());
}

WApplication *createApplication(const WEnvironment& env)
{
  /*
   * You could read information from the environment to decide whether
   * the user has permission to start a new application
   */
  return new HelloApplication(env);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  /*
   * Your main method may set up some shared resources, but should then
   * start the server application (FastCGI or httpd) that starts listening
   * for requests, and handles all of the application life cycles.
   *
   * The last argument to WRun specifies the function that will instantiate
   * new application objects. That function is executed when a new user surfs
   * to the Wt application, and after the library has negotiated browser
   * support. The function should return a newly instantiated application
   * object.
   */
  int retval = WRun(argc, argv, &createApplication);
  char* ch = new ch();
  cin() >> ch;
  return retval;
}
```

The HelloWorldWt/CMakeLists.txt has:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)

PROJECT(WT_HELLO_WORLD)

SET (WT_CONNECTOR "wtfcgi" CACHE STRING "Connector used (wthttp or wtfcgi)")

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(source)
```

The HelloWorldWt/source/CMakeLists.txt has

```
SET(WT_PROJECT_SOURCE
main.cpp
)

SET(WT_PROJECT_TARGET wt_project.wt)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(${WT_PROJECT_TARGET} ${WT_PROJECT_SOURCE})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${WT_PROJECT_TARGET} ${WT_CONNECTOR} wt)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("C:/Users/Me/My Code Libraries/wt-3.3.1/src")
```

I then ran

```
cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles" from the MyCode directory
```

That created a few files,
  this created cmake_install.cmake, among other files.

I then ran: cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles" from HelloWorldWt/source
then I ran: cmake -P cmake_install.cmake

I then had:
My Code\HelloWorldWt\source\build\CMakeFiles\2.8.12\CompilerIdCXX\a.exe file, and I clicked that program to run it, and a console window just opened then closed.

what am I missing here?, I am trying to get a Wt application running, but can't seem to do it yet

(Maybe I should note that when I use the command:

```
cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
```

the cmd console, replies with

```
-- Install configuration: ""
```

and then goes back to the prompt. - If that helps).

Comment: Don't click it from inside explorer.  Run cmd (by shift right clicking on CompilerIdCXX and choosing Open Command window here) and then execute it from the command line - that will show you the error that is being printed out because the window won't close that way.

Comment: When I run a.exe from that folder, the console prints no message and finishes immediately, doing nothing.

Comment: Are all needed libraries in PATH ?

Comment: I didn't add any libraries to path - didn't know I need to - I am very new to Wt. Are you talking about dll's? What libraries would I need to add?

Comment: You should check [this out](http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/projects/wt/wiki/Frequently_Asked_Questions).

Comment: You are missing basic usage of cmake. CMake only generates the build files, but it does _not_ actually compile it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 My Code\HelloWorldWt\source\build\CMakeFiles\2.8.12\CompilerIdCXX\a.exe
```

Is **not the file you want to run**. It is an internal CMake test cmake creates during configuration to verify that the selected compiler even compiles and detect the target architecture.

You executable **will be called**

```
My Code\HelloWorldWt\source\build\wt_project.wt.exe
```

**when you actually compile it**.

To compile it, you either call `make`, or other appropriate build command depending on the selected generator, or you can ask `cmake` to call it for you with the command:

```
cmake --build .
```

The code you pasted contains syntax error—

```
cin() >> ch;
```

should be

```
std::cin >> ch;
```

(and `ch` should be a `char`, not `char *`)—which confirms you didn't yet try to compile it.

I should add that brief look at the WT documentation suggests the resulting executable should also need a bunch of options before it does anything interesting too.

Answer (score -2):

We are using g++ since its a c++ interface (opposed to gcc), and scons as the build model.  This works well and was pretty simple to deploy.  I would suggest trying the next Ubuntu 14.04 release as it will contain a stable Wt version in its packages.

Comment: This does not appear to be relevant, -1. CMake knows well enough to use appropriate C++ compiler driver for anything with extension `.cpp` and trying on Ubuntu won't help solve anything on Windows (GNU/Linux might be better for development than Windows, but that does not make it relevant for Windows-specific question).